# Symfony - easyAdmin changing 'list.row_actions'

Tags: symfony

Currently I'm using Symfony 3 and implementing Easy Admin backend.

By default, the label available show as something like 'list.row_actions'.

I have read the documentation for Easy Admin, and manage to edit certain label such as Edit and Delete.

But come to confusion why I cannot edit the 'list.row_actions on the list table header.

[image: cannot change list.row_actions label]

The same problem I have with the Edit page, specifically the buttons:

[image]

Here is some of the configurations I add into config.yml under easy_admin tree:

> config.yml

```
list:

  actions:
    - { name: 'new', label: 'New' }
    - { name: 'search', label: 'Search' }
    - { name: 'edit', label: 'Edit' }

    - { name: 'delete', label: 'Delete' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several tweaking and failures, I have found a solution, it was documented but I did not expect it to be documented there nested.

Here's the github page: [Advanced Design Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/list-search-show-configuration.html)

We will overwrite the default html.twig file by overriding the `{{ block }}`

### Create an Overwrite Folder

First, create a folder `easy_admin` inside Resources\views.

Suppose you want to change `list.row_actions`, head over to the source file from `easy-admin` usually inside:

```
vendor\javiereguiluz\easyadmin-bundle\views\includes\ In the last version
```

### Finding the source

Find the `list.html.twig` file and check out its content for a brief. If you CTRL + F (Find) for `list.row_actions`, it will show you directly something like this. Now copy the whole `block`

```
        {% block table_head %}
        <tr>
            {% for field, metadata in fields %}
                {% set isSortingField = metadata.property == app.request.get('sortField') %}
                {% set nextSortDirection = isSortingField ? (app.request.get('sortDirection') == 'DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC') : 'DESC' %}
                {% set _column_label = (metadata.label ?: field|humanize)|trans(_trans_parameters) %}
                {% set _column_icon = isSortingField ? (nextSortDirection == 'DESC' ? 'fa-caret-up' : 'fa-caret-down') : 'fa-sort' %}

                <th data-property-name="{{ metadata.property }}" class="{{ isSortingField ? 'sorted' }} {{ metadata.virtual ? 'virtual' }} {{ metadata.dataType|lower }} {{ metadata.css_class }}">
                    {% if metadata.sortable %}
                        <a href="{{ path('easyadmin', _request_parameters|merge({ sortField: metadata.property, sortDirection: nextSortDirection })) }}">
                            <i class="fa {{ _column_icon }}"></i>
                            {{ _column_label|raw }}
                        </a>
                    {% else %}
                        <span>{{ _column_label|raw }}</span>
                    {% endif %}
                </th>
            {% endfor %}

            {% if _list_item_actions|length > 0 %}
                <th>
                    <span>{{ 'list.row_actions'|trans(_trans_parameters, 'EasyAdminBundle') }}</span>
                </th>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
    {% endblock table_head %}
```

### Pasting to Overwrite File

To paste/overwrite this, you need to create a file with exact name as the filename where you copied it. In this case, `list.html.twig`. Then paste it inside the file

IMPORTANT : At top of the file, include this tag -

```
{% extends '@EasyAdmin/default/list.html.twig' %}

{% block table_head %}
<tr>
    {% for field, metadata in fields %}
    ...code continues...
```

---

#### Why overwrite?

If you edit the file from the source code, you will have trouble deploying it especially if you're using git clone and then composer update.

Overwriting make sure that the code persist even when you deploy it.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue. As for me, I fixed it easier.

First of all try to use this

```
# app/config/config.yml (Symfony3)
# config/packages/framework.yaml (Symfony4)
framework:
   translator:     { fallbacks: "%locale%" }
```

But if you want to override with your translation, create this file:

```
# translations/EasyAdminBundle.en.yaml
list.row_actions: "My actions"
```